# VBA Issue Excel

Tags: excel, vba, office365

i am trying to add a translator in Excel, but i can't figure out where the mistake is in my Code: I am trying to add a translator in Excel via VBA.
The problem i am having is that i can't identify the error in my code below.
I am not that profficient in Vba, and i need some help and guidance on it. The translator was mostly thought by myself, and with a little help from youtoube from a guy.

```
    Option Explicit
Dim Output As String

Sub Google_Translate()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim i, colcnt As Interior
co1cnt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
For i = 1 To co1cnt
    If Cells(1, i).Value <> "" Then
        
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = x1calculationAutomatic
End Sub

Public Function autotranslate(ByVal Text As String, Optional LanguageFrom As LanguageCode, Optional Languageto As LanguageCode) As String

    
    Dim angfrom As String, langto As String, ie As InternetExplorer, url As String, myarray
    If IsMissing(LanguageFrom) Then
        LanguageFrom = inputAuto
    End If
    If IsMissing(Languageto) Then
        Languageto = returnEnglish
    End If
        
        myarray = Split(langcode, ",")
        langfrom = myarray(LanguageFrom)
        langto = myarray(Languageto)
        
        url = "Http://translate.google.com/#" & langfrom & "/" & langto & "/" & Text
        
        Set ie = New InternetExplorer
        ie.Visible = False
        ie.navigate url
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
        Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
          
        
        Dim doc As HTMLDocument
        Set doc = ie.Document
        autotranslate = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("tlid-translation translation")(0).innerText
        Output = autotranslate
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
        
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of small errors in your code that are subtle and hard to find if you just copy a chunk of code rather than build it up step by step.
Some examples:

```
Dim i, colcnt As Interior
co1cnt = ...
```

`Interior` is probably meant to be `Integer`.
The variable is declared as `colcnt` but you wrote `co1cnt` (with digit 1 instead of L) on the next row.
The `For` statement is missing its `Next`. Same goes for `If`, missing its `End If`.

There is a lot more. Start over and build it up one step at a time.